# Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients for 8 in $3 \otimes \bar 3 $ and the $6$ in $3 \otimes 3$ of $SU(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

Do Tables for the Clebsch Gordan coefficients for the decomposition of the $8$ dimensional irrep of $SU(3)$ into $3 \otimes \bar 3 $ and the $6$ in $3 \otimes 3$ (in the Dynkin basis) exist somewhere? (Of course, I googled and searched on my own for quite a while, but was unable to find anything useful)

*I tried to compute them by hand, but I'm not entirely sure when it comes to normalization of the states. Especially, lowering the degenerate $(0,0)$ state is problematic, because there are four possibilities, which lead to two different states, but with different numerical coefficients.*

I tried to compute them using a software called [CleGo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4008), which gave me

[[[("1", ("(0,-1,)1", "(-1,0,)1"))]];

[[("2", ("(0,-1,)1", "(1,-1,)1"))]; [("1", ("(-1,1,)1", "(-1,0,)1"))]];

[[("1", ("(-1,1,)1", "(1,-1,)1")); ("1", ("(1,0,)1", "(-1,0,)1"))];
  [("1", ("(0,-1,)1", "(0,1,)1")); ("1", ("(-1,1,)1", "(1,-1,)1"))]];

[[("1", ("(1,0,)1", "(1,-1,)1"))]; [("1", ("(-1,1,)1", "(0,1,)1"))]];

[[("1", ("(1,0,)1", "(0,1,)1"))]]]

and I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1):

The calculations are reasonably straightforward for your specific cases.

The simplest approach is to consider the states in $(1,0)$ to be the 1-excitations states of the 3D harmonic oscillator: $\{\vert 100\rangle,\vert 010\rangle,\vert 001\rangle\}$.   For a state $\vert n_1n_2n_3\rangle$, the weight is $[n_1-n_2,n_2-n_3]$.  There is no weight multiplicity in $(1,0)$ so $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ uniquely label a basis in the irrep.

The states in $(2,0)$ must then, by Schur-Weyl duality, be in the symmetric part of $(1,0)\otimes(1,0)$.  It follows immediately by additivity of weights and permutation symmetry that 
\begin{align}
\vert 200\rangle &= \vert 100\rangle\vert 100\rangle \, ,\\
\vert 110\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\vert 100\rangle\vert 010\rangle+\vert 010\rangle\vert 100\rangle\right)
\end{align}
and so forth for the other states in $(2,0)$.

The case of $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$ can be handled in the same general manner, provided you construct the states in $(0,1)$ as the antisymmetric part of $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$.   You can then construct states in $(1,1)$ as 3-particle states.

Thus, for instance, the highest weight state of $(0,1)$ is
$$
\vert(0,1)110\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\vert 100\rangle \vert 010\rangle - \vert 010\rangle \vert 110\rangle\right)
$$
and the highest weight state of $(1,1)$ will then be 
$$
\vert (1,1)210\rangle = \vert 100\rangle \vert (0,1)110\rangle. \tag{1}
$$
The irrep (1,1) has 2 states of weight $0$.  It is not hard to find they are of the form
$$
\vert\psi\rangle = a\vert 100\rangle \vert(01)011\rangle + b
\vert 010\rangle \vert(01)\vert 101\rangle + c\vert 001\rangle \vert (01)\vert 110\rangle \tag{2}
$$
These must be orthogonal to the singlet state in $(0,0)$.  This singlet state is in fact the determinant of the three-particle states
$$
\vert (0,0)111\rangle =
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\vert 100\rangle & \vert 010\rangle &\vert 001\rangle \\
\vert 010\rangle &\vert 001\rangle &\vert 100\rangle \\
\vert 001\rangle & \vert 100\rangle &\vert 010\rangle
\end{array}\right) \tag{3}
$$
The zero-weight states in (1,1) must be orthogonal to (3).  If you use the standard $su(2)\oplus u(1)$ basis, you can construct a state with $J=0$ by forcing the coefficients in (2) to be give you a null state when acting on (2) using any operator in the $su(2)$ subalgebra in addition to being orthogonal to (3).  The last state with zero-weight is a $J=1$ state.  You can construct it by orthgonality to the $J=0$ state of $(1,1)$ and the $(0,0)$ state.

All other states are uniquely labelled by weights so they have a form,  in terms of $(1,0)\otimes(0,1)$ states, obtained by suitable modification of (1).

[This wikipage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU%283%29) gives additional references.  There is also [this online CG calculator](http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~vondelft/Papers/ClebschGordan/) which might be useful.  As always, the difficulties are with the notation and the relative phases of the multiplets (unlike the $su(2)$ case, there is nothing like the Condon-Shortley phase convention in $su(3)$, and this has caused considerable pain to external users of a specific convention.)